# Lord of the Ring LCG: Lindon Navigator

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings-lcg

While using Lindon Navigator to quest, does the forced effects trigger if and only if the quest card is discarded, or after every quest phase?

**Lindon Navigator** (Ally)

> Lindon Navigator does not exhaust to commit to a quest, and can commit to quests while exhausted.
>
> **Forced**: After resolving a quest to which Lindon Navigator was committed, either discard it from play or discard 1 card from your hand.

The key word being "resolving", I'm not sure which interpretation is the right one.

Comment: As per my understanding of the phrasing, it will trigger each time you resolve a quest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quest is 'resolved' during the quest resolution step of the Quest Phase. This happens every quest phase. So Lindon Navigator's forced effect triggers after the quest resolution step of each Quest Phase regardless of the outcome. Note that this does not technically happen at the end of the Quest Phase as there is still an action window and the quest phase end step.

The quest card is discarded when the quest 'advances' (usually when the quest has progress tokens equal the current quest's quest points; this may happen outside of the quest resolution step by the way). This is different from 'resolution' which happens every Quest Phase during the quest resolution step (unless of course that step is skipped by a card effect).

Source: The Lord of the Rings: The Card Game Online Rules Reference available on the FFG website https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/products/the-lord-of-the-rings-the-card-game/.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was using this card wrong then :D